# Call a bootstrap modal from a joint js rect object

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal, jointjs

i got a joint.js rect and i want to call a bootstrap modal from it as if it be a button, this is the rect code :

```
var rectdetail = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: { x: 450, y: y_value +10},
    size: { width: 130, height: 35 },
    attrs: { 
        rect: { fill: '#333','stroke-width': 0 },
        text: {
            text: 'Detail',
            fill: 'white'
        }
    }
});
```

And this is the modal code i have in my html template :

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
      aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Registrar grupo</h4>
      </div>
      <form>
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="modal-body">
            <br/>
                <div class="row">

                        Hello, it's working allright !!

                </div>
          </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how ?, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in point.js doc [here](http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Paper%3aevents),

you have some events you can handle.

Code is like this:

```
 paper.on('blank:pointerdown', function(evt, x, y) { 
    alert('pointerdown on a blank area in the paper.')
})
```

Now, you can use bootstrap.js to show your modal.

That's code if you have jquery:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already tried that paper.on event, but it triggers in every object on paper, do you know how to make it work just clicking in my rect ??

Comment: `paper.on('element:pointerup', function(elementView) {
  if (elementView.model.id === rectdetail.id) showModal(); });` or `rectdetail.findView(paper).on('element:pointerup', function() { showModal(); });`